# TeX rendering in a java application

Tags: java, latex, rendering, tex

I want to render math formulas in my Java GUI application. I am looking for a library made for computer use, not web use, which can render TeX. I have already tried jLatexMath, but it's very slow when I use it in my application.

If there are any other/better, could you point me in the right direction?

*(If this question belongs on the TeX forum, I'll move it there)*

Comment: You'll probably have more luck at http://tex.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Why? I think the people that know anything about Java libraries come on SO. I'll also post it on TeX.SE, and see what the input is!

Comment: I think it worked: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41609/5763

Comment: Please wait for a mod to migrate questions between sites, please don't cross-post. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The question is indeed close to being answered on TeX.